# Umbraco 6.2.0 Render maco inside a razor macroscript

Tags: umbraco

I have the below code which works but is there a better way using the RenderMacroContent method.  Not sure how to add parameters to that.

```
<umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">@{
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(this.Output);
var macroPressLogin = new umbraco.presentation.templateControls.Macro();
macroPressLogin.Alias = "Security-PressLogin";
macroPressLogin.Attributes.Add("TargetNode", Parameter.TargetNode);
macroPressLogin.RenderControl(writer);   }</umbraco:Macro>
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your view inherits from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage` or `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<YourModel>` you should just be able to write something like:

```
@Umbraco.RenderMacro("MacroAlias", new { ParameterAlias1 = "value1", ParameterAlias2 = "value2" })
```

So in your case it would be:

```
@Umbraco.RenderMacro("Security-PressLogin", new { TargetNode = "targetNodeValue" })
```

If you're talking about calling one macro from within another then this should also work as long as your macro partial view inherits from `Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage`

From your example it looks like you're working with a legacy razor macro using `umbraco.MacroEngines`.  If possible I would recommend upgrading to a partial view macro.  [Click here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Macros/Partial-View-Macros/) for some further info.

Comment: Thanks but not using mvc.  RenderMacroContent with params is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a year old, but I hope someone finds a use for this information (using Umbraco version 6.x):

```
@(Html.Raw(umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent("<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias=\"MacroAliasHere\" dynamicParameter=\""+ @dynamicValue + "\" staticParameter=\"staticValue\" ></?UMBRACO_MACRO>", Model.Id)))
```

Option number 2, which I prefer, is actually code to output a contour form using a value from the form picker datatype:

```
var helper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
@Html.Raw(helper.RenderMacro("umbracoContour.RazorRenderForm", new { formGuid = @Model.formPickerAlias }))
```